# What is a function's signature? [LaTeX3]

Tags: macros, expl3

I am trying to understand the interface3 documentation.

The [LaTeX Interface 3 documentation](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel?lang=en) v. May 20, 2014 and March 1, 2015 refer to Defining new functions using the signature in section 3.3. I am wondering what it means when it states that:

> Within the code, the number of parameters is detected automatically from the function signature.

(It probably should read: "Within the code, the number of parameters is detected automatically **by** the function'**s** signature.)

## Example function using LaTeX 3 expl3 syntax:

```
\cs_new:Nn <function> {<code>}
```

Where are the parameters in that in contrast to:

```
\cs_new:Npn <function> <parameters> {<code>}
```

Comment: In computer science, a function's signature is the return type and the type of the arguments.

Comment: The signature are the chars behind the colon: `\your_special_function:Nnn` has three arguments (N, n, n).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sounds like an answer to me :-)

Comment: That sentence doesn't refer that a function `\foo:nn` knows how many arguments it has itself; it means that `\cs_new:Nn` will calculate the number of arguments from the signature it sees. That is, with `\cs_new:Nn \foo:NNnn` the `\cs_new:Nn` will extract the `NNnn` (the *signature*, after the colon) and counting it will se thath `\foo:NNnn` should have 4 arguments, so it will expand, somehow, to `\cs_new:Npn \foo:NNnn #1 #2 #3 #4` and then will define a macro (traditionally that would be `\def\foowhatever#1#2#3#4`. I think that's the part you misunderstood, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function name should be of the form

```
\<prefix>_<name>:<signature>
```

where `<prefix>` is a string of letters, possibly preceded by `__`, and `<name>` is a string of letters and underscores that should remind the function's role.

The `<signature>` is a string of letters among `NnTFcofxVvwp`, that should reflect the number of arguments the function has.

However, a function defined with

```
\cs_new:Nn
\cs_new_protected:Nn
\cs_new_nopar:Nn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn
```

or the `\cs_set` analogs, should only have a signature consisting of characters among `NnTF`. Actually `T` and `F` are essentially the same as `n` and should be used only for functions doing conditional business.

If you say

```
\cs_new:Nn \my_function:nn { <replacement text> }
```

you can use `#1` and `#2` in the replacement text just as if you had said

```
\cs_new:Npn \my_function:nn #1 #2 { <replacement text> }
```

because `\cs_new:Nn` examines its first argument and is able to figure out how many arguments to supply in the parameter text.

The signature of `\tl_set:Nx` is `Nx` meaning that it has two arguments, the first of which is a token (the name of the variable to set); the second argument is a normal braced argument, which is subject to full expansion before the value assignment is performed; the `protected` bit is because a value assignment is involved. However you can't define it as

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tl_set:Nx { <replacement text> }
```

but you *must* do

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tl_set:Nn { <replacement text> }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Nx }
```

Note that you can define function with no signature in their name, but in this case the “long form”

```
\cs_new:Npn
\cs_new_protected:Npn
\cs_new_nopar:Npn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn
```

should be used, with the parameter text fully spelled out. The same if you want to define functions with `w` in the signature.

Answer (score 2):

The signature are the chars behind the colon: `\your_special_function:Nnn` has three arguments (N, n, n).